# MS Access - field_AfterUpdate

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to lock a separate combobox on a form when another one is filled.  Below is the code, however it's not doing anything and I'm unsure why.

```
Private Sub fieldApplicationType_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.fieldApplicationType.Value Like "Application" Then
        Me.fieldPrimaryBusinessFunction.Enabled = True
    Else:
        Me.fieldPrimaryBusinessFunction.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

The value being displayed in the form is the "name" field on the table.  Basically if the name contains "Application" I want to disable the other combobox so it can't be used.

Bonus Points on how do I get this to combobox to stay disabled if the form already has the fieldApplicationType selected as NOT Application?

The Update does not seem to be called and maybe it's due to the following?

There is a Form_Current() which calls a module.  I didn't design this code but guessing that Module is taking precident over the form Events?

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    ' Temporarily turn off screen refreshes while we update widget states.
    ' For some reason, if this isn't done MS Access doesn't consistently repaint all controls
    application.Echo False

    Call UpdateManagementFormReadonlyState(Me, _
                                 Me.lblReadOnlyStatusIndicator, _
                                 hasEditPermissionsForManagementFields(Me.recordOwnerId.Value))


    ' Re-enable normal GUI updates
    application.Echo True
End Sub
```

Comment: weird it didn't show anything?  The value is updated though.

Comment: I put the msg box on `Form_AfterUpdate()` and it returned the integer so I guess I need to do a lookup based on the ID that's returned?  why won't it trigger on the field update?

Comment: `MsgBox` did not display at all.

Comment: I think I know the problem.  Updating with new info.

Comment: Since you said `fieldApplicationType.Value` returns an integer, there is no way it can ever be `Like "Application"`  So I'm fairly certain that is a logic error, but don't know whether that's the only problem you're facing.